# Activity is not in manifest but executes anyway

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm getting "build failed" errors when I execute my package which are in one of my activities ("MainActivity").

However, I purposefully excluded this activity from the manifest, so I don't understand why it's executing.

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Do errors in activities affect the build, even when they aren't executed/in the manifest?

Comment: Having an activity not in the manifest is fine, so long as nobody launches that activity.  If someone does, that's an automatic error at runtime.  But you really need to post your error.